# What does "basic rates" and "other rates" mean when using `netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid`

Tags: windows, wifi, wireless, netsh

When I run this command:

```
netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid
```

I get this result:

```
Interface name : WiFi
There are 1 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : *********
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : **********
    Encryption              : **********
    BSSID 1                 : **********
         Signal             : 93%
         Radio type         : 802.11n
         Channel            : 52
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 6 12 24
         Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54
```

I was wondering what does the Basic rates (Mbps) and Other rates (Mbps) mean?

I read this comparison table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009#Comparison

And it seems that the numbers correspond to all stream data rates column for 802.11g row. Why is there a separation between basic rates and other rates? What is the significance of the numbers? What can I use this information for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why there is a seperation, but here is the documentation for the WLAN_RATE_SET, which is probably the Wlan API structure netsh is trying to display here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370026(v=vs.85).aspx

> A basic rate is the data transfer rate that all stations in a basic service set (BSS) can use to receive frames from the wireless medium

I would guess that is the first line you are seeing. As to what the "other" rate set is, I'm not sure.

Comment: So it's saying that all stations in the current BSS can use 6 or 12 or 24 Mbps? Why such a range? Why not all use the max possible data rate?

Comment: I've been doing a bit more searching as I wasn't sure myself.. googling "basic rate set" has proven fruitful.

It seems that the basic rate set is the router advertising what rates it can communicate with, not the actual rate of data transfer. Think 802.11a,b,etc..

In order for a client to associate with an AP, it needs to support all of the basic rates. So an old client that only supports rates 1 and 2 would not be able to connect to the AP in your post.

This page has some nice definitions: http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRT610N/1.00.00.17/en_help/Advanced_Wireless_Settings.htm

Comment: So those data rate is what the current BSSID supports? And my current connection is using one of those rates, but the information doesn't tell which rate is being used. Whereas the other rates are rates that aren't supported? I wonder why it didn't just tell you what the rate it is currently using?

Comment: Any ideas why it's a continuous range? Why does it jump from 6, 12 to 24?

Comment: I don't think the other rates are unsupported, just that they are optional. In order to connect to the AP, you must support at least 6 12 24. But the router could also send at 9 18 36 48 54 if it wanted. You still must have 6, 12, and 24 though. So an 802.11b client could not connect.

Maybe you could get the current transmit rate some other way, but I don't think that is what the basic rate set is intended for. The rate set is to know what you need to get connected. I don't know how you could get the current transmit rate.

I don't know why it is not continuous.

Comment: When you said rate set, 6, 12, 24, does this mean an actual data rate can be at 6 or at 12 or at 24 Mbps?

Comment: I'm wondering how you can calculate/extract the basic rates vs other rates from the API referenced in this answer. I don't get the same list returned as combining the basic rates + other rates from the netsh command. The API output doesn't provide separate sets for the basic rate & other rates either.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: that linksys link is dead; it's saved in the [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512022430/http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRT610N/1.00.00.17/en_help/Advanced_Wireless_Settings.htm) wayback machine.